# In a map table, I need to select a subset on rows for each individual

Tags: sql

I have a table with 3 columns a, b and weight representing a persons mappings. The table has +- 1 T of rows.

The simple problem can be explained like:

I need the top 20 relation for a givin a, something like:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE a = ? ORDER BY weight LIMIT 20;
```

The real problem is that I need to do this for 1000 a, and doing this query 1000 times is slow. My question is: how can I do it in a single SQL query.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Row_number()` function. I have assumed the top 20 based on the weight (i.e order by weight) here.

To get all the a's top 20 records;

```
select a,b, weight 
from (
    select a,b, weight, Row_number() over (partition by a order by weight) rn
    from my_table  
) AB
where rn<21
order by rn
```

To get a single a's top 20 records;

```
select top(20) a,b, weight
from my_table
where a = yourValue
order by weight
```

Comment: You might want to consider avoiding RANK() because of it's behaviour with ties. Perhaps ROW_NUMBER()? Will upvote on change, if you agree.

Comment: The `LIMIT` clause makes me suppose he is using MySql. So no `PARTITION BY` analytic functions or `TOP`...

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution:

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table t1
 WHERE 20 <= ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.a=t1.a AND t2.weight < t1.weight)
 ORDER BY a, weight;
```